# Convert a Bits8 to a `Subset Nat (`LT` 256)`

Tags: proof, idris, dependent-type

I have the following module:

```
module Nat256

import Data.DPair
import Data.Bits

public export
bits8ToNat256 : Bits8 -> Subset Nat (`LT` 256)
bits8ToNat256 i =
  case i of
  0   => 0
  1   => 1
  2   => 2
  3   => 3
  4   => 4
  5   => 5
  6   => 6
  7   => 7
  8   => 8
  9   => 9
  10  => 10
  11  => 11
  12  => 12
  13  => 13
  14  => 14
  15  => 15
  16  => 16
  17  => 17
  18  => 18
  19  => 19
  20  => 20
  21  => 21
  22  => 22
  23  => 23
  24  => 24
  25  => 25
  26  => 26
  27  => 27
  28  => 28
  29  => 29
  30  => 30
  31  => 31
  32  => 32
  33  => 33
  34  => 34
  35  => 35
  36  => 36
  37  => 37
  38  => 38
  39  => 39
  40  => 40
  41  => 41
  42  => 42
  43  => 43
  44  => 44
  45  => 45
  46  => 46
  47  => 47
  48  => 48
  49  => 49
  50  => 50
  51  => 51
  52  => 52
  53  => 53
  54  => 54
  55  => 55
  56  => 56
  57  => 57
  58  => 58
  59  => 59
  60  => 60
  61  => 61
  62  => 62
  63  => 63
  64  => 64
  65  => 65
  66  => 66
  67  => 67
  68  => 68
  69  => 69
  70  => 70
  71  => 71
  72  => 72
  73  => 73
  74  => 74
  75  => 75
  76  => 76
  77  => 77
  78  => 78
  79  => 79
  80  => 80
  81  => 81
  82  => 82
  83  => 83
  84  => 84
  85  => 85
  86  => 86
  87  => 87
  88  => 88
  89  => 89
  90  => 90
  91  => 91
  92  => 92
  93  => 93
  94  => 94
  95  => 95
  96  => 96
  97  => 97
  98  => 98
  99  => 99
  100 => 100
  101 => 101
  102 => 102
  103 => 103
  104 => 104
  105 => 105
  106 => 106
  107 => 107
  108 => 108
  109 => 109
  110 => 110
  111 => 111
  112 => 112
  113 => 113
  114 => 114
  115 => 115
  116 => 116
  117 => 117
  118 => 118
  119 => 119
  120 => 120
  121 => 121
  122 => 122
  123 => 123
  124 => 124
  125 => 125
  126 => 126
  127 => 127
  128 => 128
  129 => 129
  130 => 130
  131 => 131
  132 => 132
  133 => 133
  134 => 134
  135 => 135
  136 => 136
  137 => 137
  138 => 138
  139 => 139
  140 => 140
  141 => 141
  142 => 142
  143 => 143
  144 => 144
  145 => 145
  146 => 146
  147 => 147
  148 => 148
  149 => 149
  150 => 150
  151 => 151
  152 => 152
  153 => 153
  154 => 154
  155 => 155
  156 => 156
  157 => 157
  158 => 158
  159 => 159
  160 => 160
  161 => 161
  162 => 162
  163 => 163
  164 => 164
  165 => 165
  166 => 166
  167 => 167
  168 => 168
  169 => 169
  170 => 170
  171 => 171
  172 => 172
  173 => 173
  174 => 174
  175 => 175
  176 => 176
  177 => 177
  178 => 178
  179 => 179
  180 => 180
  181 => 181
  182 => 182
  183 => 183
  184 => 184
  185 => 185
  186 => 186
  187 => 187
  188 => 188
  189 => 189
  190 => 190
  191 => 191
  192 => 192
  193 => 193
  194 => 194
  195 => 195
  196 => 196
  197 => 197
  198 => 198
  199 => 199
  200 => 200
  201 => 201
  202 => 202
  203 => 203
  204 => 204
  205 => 205
  206 => 206
  207 => 207
  208 => 208
  209 => 209
  210 => 210
  211 => 211
  212 => 212
  213 => 213
  214 => 214
  215 => 215
  216 => 216
  217 => 217
  218 => 218
  219 => 219
  220 => 220
  221 => 221
  222 => 222
  223 => 223
  224 => 224
  225 => 225
  226 => 226
  227 => 227
  228 => 228
  229 => 229
  230 => 230
  231 => 231
  232 => 232
  233 => 233
  234 => 234
  235 => 235
  236 => 236
  237 => 237
  238 => 238
  239 => 239
  240 => 240
  241 => 241
  242 => 242
  243 => 243
  244 => 244
  245 => 245
  246 => 246
  247 => 247
  248 => 248
  249 => 249
  250 => 250
  251 => 251
  252 => 252
  253 => 253
  254 => 254
  255 => 255
```

When I compile it, I get this error after an hour of compiling:

```
1/1: Building Nat256 (Nat256.idr)
Error: While processing right hand side of bits8ToNat256. Can't find an implementation
for Num (Subset Nat (\{arg:0} => LT arg (fromInteger 256))).

Nat256:10:10--10:11
 06 | public export
 07 | bits8ToNat256 : Bits8 -> Subset Nat (`LT` 256)
 08 | bits8ToNat256 i =
 09 |   case i of
 10 |   0   => 0
               ^
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, since zero is a perfectly valid natural number in Idris. The following works:

```
> the Nat 0
0
```

How can I write this program such that it compiles, and within reasonable time?

Comment: The constructor of `Subset` is `Element`.

Comment: Also you might want to consider `Fin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `natToFin`:

```
public export
bits8ToNat256 : Bits8 -> Fin 256
bits8ToNat256 i = case natToFin (cast i) 256 of
    Just x => x
    Nothing => assert_total $ idris_crash "byte value is outside 0-255 range"
```

Comment: This crashes at runtime for every input. It always takes the Nothing branch. I am using version `4a9f00078a5d03840b702dbc3bff3c139f202389`. Which version did you test this with?

Comment: My issue was fixed with https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/pull/1862

Answer (score 0):

As @michaelmesser suggested, I used Fin. Now I only have the problems of bad performance (it is really slow) and the impossible case match. The Fin can be converted to a Nat with `finToNat`.

```
module Fin256

import Data.Fin
import Data.Bits

public export
partial
bits8ToFin256 : Bits8 -> Fin 256
bits8ToFin256 i =
  case i of
  0   => 0
  1   => 1
  2   => 2
  3   => 3
  4   => 4
  5   => 5
  6   => 6
  7   => 7
  8   => 8
  9   => 9
  10  => 10
  11  => 11
  12  => 12
  13  => 13
  14  => 14
  15  => 15
  16  => 16
  17  => 17
  18  => 18
  19  => 19
  20  => 20
  21  => 21
  22  => 22
  23  => 23
  24  => 24
  25  => 25
  26  => 26
  27  => 27
  28  => 28
  29  => 29
  30  => 30
  31  => 31
  32  => 32
  33  => 33
  34  => 34
  35  => 35
  36  => 36
  37  => 37
  38  => 38
  39  => 39
  40  => 40
  41  => 41
  42  => 42
  43  => 43
  44  => 44
  45  => 45
  46  => 46
  47  => 47
  48  => 48
  49  => 49
  50  => 50
  51  => 51
  52  => 52
  53  => 53
  54  => 54
  55  => 55
  56  => 56
  57  => 57
  58  => 58
  59  => 59
  60  => 60
  61  => 61
  62  => 62
  63  => 63
  64  => 64
  65  => 65
  66  => 66
  67  => 67
  68  => 68
  69  => 69
  70  => 70
  71  => 71
  72  => 72
  73  => 73
  74  => 74
  75  => 75
  76  => 76
  77  => 77
  78  => 78
  79  => 79
  80  => 80
  81  => 81
  82  => 82
  83  => 83
  84  => 84
  85  => 85
  86  => 86
  87  => 87
  88  => 88
  89  => 89
  90  => 90
  91  => 91
  92  => 92
  93  => 93
  94  => 94
  95  => 95
  96  => 96
  97  => 97
  98  => 98
  99  => 99
  100 => 100
  101 => 101
  102 => 102
  103 => 103
  104 => 104
  105 => 105
  106 => 106
  107 => 107
  108 => 108
  109 => 109
  110 => 110
  111 => 111
  112 => 112
  113 => 113
  114 => 114
  115 => 115
  116 => 116
  117 => 117
  118 => 118
  119 => 119
  120 => 120
  121 => 121
  122 => 122
  123 => 123
  124 => 124
  125 => 125
  126 => 126
  127 => 127
  128 => 128
  129 => 129
  130 => 130
  131 => 131
  132 => 132
  133 => 133
  134 => 134
  135 => 135
  136 => 136
  137 => 137
  138 => 138
  139 => 139
  140 => 140
  141 => 141
  142 => 142
  143 => 143
  144 => 144
  145 => 145
  146 => 146
  147 => 147
  148 => 148
  149 => 149
  150 => 150
  151 => 151
  152 => 152
  153 => 153
  154 => 154
  155 => 155
  156 => 156
  157 => 157
  158 => 158
  159 => 159
  160 => 160
  161 => 161
  162 => 162
  163 => 163
  164 => 164
  165 => 165
  166 => 166
  167 => 167
  168 => 168
  169 => 169
  170 => 170
  171 => 171
  172 => 172
  173 => 173
  174 => 174
  175 => 175
  176 => 176
  177 => 177
  178 => 178
  179 => 179
  180 => 180
  181 => 181
  182 => 182
  183 => 183
  184 => 184
  185 => 185
  186 => 186
  187 => 187
  188 => 188
  189 => 189
  190 => 190
  191 => 191
  192 => 192
  193 => 193
  194 => 194
  195 => 195
  196 => 196
  197 => 197
  198 => 198
  199 => 199
  200 => 200
  201 => 201
  202 => 202
  203 => 203
  204 => 204
  205 => 205
  206 => 206
  207 => 207
  208 => 208
  209 => 209
  210 => 210
  211 => 211
  212 => 212
  213 => 213
  214 => 214
  215 => 215
  216 => 216
  217 => 217
  218 => 218
  219 => 219
  220 => 220
  221 => 221
  222 => 222
  223 => 223
  224 => 224
  225 => 225
  226 => 226
  227 => 227
  228 => 228
  229 => 229
  230 => 230
  231 => 231
  232 => 232
  233 => 233
  234 => 234
  235 => 235
  236 => 236
  237 => 237
  238 => 238
  239 => 239
  240 => 240
  241 => 241
  242 => 242
  243 => 243
  244 => 244
  245 => 245
  246 => 246
  247 => 247
  248 => 248
  249 => 249
  250 => 250
  251 => 251
  252 => 252
  253 => 253
  254 => 254
  255 => 255
  _ => idris_crash "byte value is outside 0-255 range"
```